# Compile error after update to swift 3

Tags: swift, metal

I have a `xcodeproject` that I use for learning `Metal` with `swift`. After I update to `swift3`, I have an compile error:

> error: cannot have global constructors (llvm.global_ctors) in compute
>   Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/usr/bin/metallib
>   failed with exit code 1

[image]

which, `compute` is the name of the kernel function. It did not indicate which part of my code is coursing the error. And it did mentioned about `llvm.global_ctors`, which might be related to `build setting` part. I am not familiar with that part so I am not sure how to fix it.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try using cmd+shift+k to clean your project

Comment: Tried that. Not working.

Comment: How did you end up fixing it? I had to restart my computer I think.

Comment: Tried that too. Not working. I end up copy and paste the code to newly created file, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we can not define and access global matrix in Metal. The similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509957/metal-shading-language-multidimensional-array). I found the same problem for Swift 4.2 Xcode 10.1. I solved the problem by removing global matrix.