# Metal Shading Language - multidimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, glsl, metal

How can I convert this:

```
const vec3 GDFVectors[19] = vec3[](
                                   normalize(vec3(1, 0, 0)),
                                   normalize(vec3(0, 1, 0)),
                                   normalize(vec3(0, 0, 1)),

                                   normalize(vec3(1, 1, 1 )),
                                   normalize(vec3(-1, 1, 1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(1, -1, 1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(1, 1, -1)),

                                   normalize(vec3(0, 1, PHI+1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(0, -1, PHI+1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(PHI+1, 0, 1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(-PHI-1, 0, 1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(1, PHI+1, 0)),
                                   normalize(vec3(-1, PHI+1, 0)),

                                   normalize(vec3(0, PHI, 1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(0, -PHI, 1)),
                                   normalize(vec3(1, 0, PHI)),
                                   normalize(vec3(-1, 0, PHI)),
                                   normalize(vec3(PHI, 1, 0)),
                                   normalize(vec3(-PHI, 1, 0))
                                   );
```

so that I can use it in `Metal`? I tried:

```
constant const float3 GDFVectors[19] = {
    normalize(float3(1, 0, 0)),
    normalize(float3(0, 1, 0)),
    normalize(float3(0, 0, 1)),

    normalize(float3(1, 1, 1 )),
    normalize(float3(-1, 1, 1)),
    normalize(float3(1, -1, 1)),
    normalize(float3(1, 1, -1)),

    normalize(float3(0, 1, PHI+1)),
    normalize(float3(0, -1, PHI+1)),
    normalize(float3(PHI+1, 0, 1)),
    normalize(float3(-PHI-1, 0, 1)),
    normalize(float3(1, PHI+1, 0)),
    normalize(float3(-1, PHI+1, 0)),

    normalize(float3(0, PHI, 1)),
    normalize(float3(0, -PHI, 1)),
    normalize(float3(1, 0, PHI)),
    normalize(float3(-1, 0, PHI)),
    normalize(float3(PHI, 1, 0)),
    normalize(float3(-PHI, 1, 0))
};
```

and did not get any error. However when I try to access it:

```
float3 a = GDFVectors[0];
```

I will get this error:

> error: cannot have global constructors (llvm.global_ctors) in compute

I know is the way I initialize the `float3` array that give me issue. But I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Do you need to access this from multiple functions or just one? If just one, try moving the declaration into the function.

Comment: Multiple. I think I need to loop the array too for every functions.